# D3.js text not coming below each other and color selection

Tags: d3.js

I have created  a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/mkrrn3sz/) here with the Issue.

```
svg.append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(75);
svg.append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text("Vehicle");
```

I want the number to come on top with the text coming below, in the form of subtext. But I am unable to bring it down. Do I have to style it explicitly or else how can I achieve that??
Also, I want the outer circle to be of a color which I can change and all the examples I have seen use the color scale already available. How can I change the color by specifying a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text positions with:

```
.attr("dy", "0.5em")
```

attribute and you can return a specific color in your callback or style.

Here's an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mkrrn3sz/1/